# Flow embedded in Site is not displaying in lightning view

Tags: apex, visualforce, visual-workflow, force.com-sites, screen-flow

I have a flow and I want to make it visible to public, So I have created a VF page and embedded the flow in that VF page. And now I have that page in a Force.com site and gave all the permissions for guest users. The flow is working fine, but the only problem is that it is being displayed only in classic view. but when I preview the VF page it is displayed in Lightning view. Any inputs on how to display my flow in lightning view would be helpful.

[image]